# Xcode build failed when trying to create Cocoa-Applescript Application

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript

everyone. I am new to programming and currently I am learning building Cocoa-Applescript Application in Xcode.
The problem is that I successfully built the application by using Cocoa-Applescript according to a programming book. But today it just doesn't work. Here is what I met when I tried to build but just get a message "build failed".
[failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3gdR.png)

So how do I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Plus, I haven't insert any code into "Delegate" in Xcode. I just designed a user interface by interface builder and wanted to see the window. So I press 'build' but got 21 alert message. Yesterday I successfully launched the window and also related the button to the relevant code and get what I want. But it just doesn't work today.

Comment: show main.m File content

Comment: I delete Xcode completely and re-install it again, and problem solved. Would you be kind to tell me where can I find main.m File content? Thank you!